# How can I run ES6 JavaScript files in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I want to run a JavaScript file that imports `scoreService` from this file:

```
import axios from 'axios'
const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/api/scores'

const getAll = () => {
  const request = axios.get(baseUrl)
  return request.then(response => response.data)
}

const create = (newObject) => {
  const request = axios.post(baseUrl, newObject)
  return request.then(response => response.data)
}

const update = (id, newObject) => {
  const request = axios.put(`${baseUrl}/${id}`, newObject)
  return request.then(response => response.data)
}

const scoreService = {getAll, create, update}
export default scoreService
```

I am unable to use Node to run my file from the terminal because the `import` statement is not supported by Node. Should or how should I change the `import` statements to use `require` instead, or is there a simpler method I could try?

Comment: The `import` statement _is_ supported by Node, since v14 (and therefore in all currently-supported versions).

Comment: I get this error when running Node: `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Comment: That's because your file is not a module. To be a module, it would either have to have a `.mjs` extension (not `.js`) _or_ your `package.json` must have an entry `"type": "module"`.

Comment: And _is_ your package `"type": "module"`? Maybe read e.g. https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#type.

Comment: I added a `package.json` (with `name`, `version`, and `type` keys) at the same level as the file I'm trying to run and changed the `.js` extension to `.mjs`. Now I'm getting the following error: `internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module ... imported from myscript.mjs`

Answer (score 0):

After installing `axios`:

yourFile.js:

```
const axios = require('axios');

const getAll = () => {
  const request = axios.get(baseUrl)
  return request.then(response => response.data)
}

const create = (newObject) => {
  const request = axios.post(baseUrl, newObject)
  return request.then(response => response.data)
}

const update = (id, newObject) => {
  const request = axios.put(`${baseUrl}/${id}`, newObject)
  return request.then(response => response.data)
}

export default scoreService = {getAll, create, update};
```

Comment: This works, but is there a way to do this without changing the import statement? How will using `require` change my script performance?

Comment: It won't affect the performance of the code execution at all.

Comment: Then is there a reason to use `import` at all when `require` exists?

Comment: The language constantly gets updated and new features are added. But, millions of apps are not updated up to the new version of the language. Therefore both (and older) versions of the language exist in harmony.